# 400 Bad Request for $http post method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

While using the following code, I get

> 400 Bad request rest_missing_callback_params

```js
$scope.signUp = function () {
    var data = {
     email: $scope.email,
     password: $scope.password,
     first_name: $scope.fName,
     last_name: $scope.lName,
     username: $scope.uName,
     billing: {
      first_name: $scope.fName,
      last_name: $scope.lName,
      company: $scope.cName,
      address_1: $scope.address1,
      address_2: $scope.address2,
      city: $scope.city,
      state: $scope.state,
      postcode: $scope.pcode,
      country: $scope.country,
      email: $scope.email,
      phone: $scope.mobile,
     },
     shipping: {
      first_name: $scope.fName1,
      last_name: $scope.lName1,
      company: $scope.cName1,
      address_1: $scope.address11,
      address_2: $scope.address12,
      city: $scope.city1,
      state: $scope.state1,
      postcode: $scope.pcode1,
      country: $scope.country1,
     }
    }

    console.log(data)
    $http.post("https://www.colourssoftware.com/wordpress/wp-json/wc/v1/customers", {
      headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
       'Authorization': 'Basic ' + window.btoa("username:password")
      },
      data: data
     })
     .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response)
     }, function (response) {
      console.log(response);
     });
}
```

But when I use the following code, it posts the data to the server.

```js
var au = window.btoa("username:password"),
    req = {
     method: 'POST',
     url: 'https://www.colourssoftware.com/wordpress/wp-json/wc/v1/customers',
     headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + au
     },
     data: data
    }

$http(req).then(function (response) {
 console.log(response)
}, function (response) {
 console.log(response);
});
```

What is the difference between these two? Why does it happen like so?

Comment: check the developer tools network tab ... see what is sent in each request, if you spot the difference, you'll have your answer

Comment: Even though iam sending email and password it gives the error missing email and password

Comment: so, there's absolutely no difference in the request headers or the post parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the top example to work you need to change this:

```
$http.post("https://www.colourssoftware.com/wordpress/wp-json/wc/v1/customers", {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + window.btoa("username:password")
  },
  data: data
})
```

To this:

```
$http.post("https://www.colourssoftware.com/wordpress/wp-json/wc/v1/customers", data, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + window.btoa("username:password")
  }
})
```

According the the Angular `$http` docs (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post) `$http.post()` has a different method signature (`post(url, data, [config]);`) than `$http()` (`$http(config)`).